# Writing to a file replaces previous contents instead of combining

Tags: c++

Everything works perfectly fine but the thing is that i want the program to loop through all the credentials in the record.txt file and if it finds a match it should grant permission for login.
please i really need some help on this
And please i've removed lot of the inputs for easier reviewing

The Code is :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
        cout << "HELLO!, WELCOME TO KINGS BANK" << endl;

        int User_Activity;

        cout << endl << endl << "1.Create Account   2.Log into existing account" << endl << endl;
        cin >> User_Activity;

        if((User_Activity < 1 || User_Activity > 2)){

        do{
            cout << endl << endl << "Input Error please try again " << endl;
            cout << endl << endl << "1.Create Account   2.Log into existing account" << endl << endl;
            cin >> User_Activity;
        }
        while (User_Activity < 1 || User_Activity > 2);
        }

        string FirstName;
        string LastName;
        string Email;
        string Digital_Address;
        string Nationality_Option;
        string DOB;
        string Occupation;
        string Password;
        string User_Account_Type;
        string Currency_type;
        string User_Title;
        string Nationality;
        string Telephone;
        string Marital_Status;
        string Pass_word;
        int ACN;
        int Currency;
        int Title;
        int Origin;
        int Status;
        int Register;
        int Account_Type;
        int Account_Number;

        if (User_Activity == 1){

        ofstream RecordFile;
        RecordFile.open("record.txt", std::ios_base::app);
        ofstream User_Credentials;
        User_Credentials.open("credentials.txt");

        cout << endl << endl << "Please follow the On-Screen Questions to proceed" << endl << endl;
        cout << endl << "1.Savings Account   2.Money Market Account   3.Checking Account" << endl << endl;
        cin >> Account_Type;

        if (Account_Type == 1){
            User_Account_Type = "Savings Account";
        }
         if (Account_Type == 2){
            User_Account_Type = "Money Market Savings";
        }
         if (Account_Type == 3){
            User_Account_Type = "Checking Account";
        }
        if (Account_Type < 1 || Account_Type > 3){
        do{
            cout << endl << endl << "Input Error please try again " << endl;
            cout << endl << "1.Savings Account   2.Money Market Account   3.Checking Account" << endl << endl;
            cin >> Account_Type;
        }
        while (Account_Type < 1 || Account_Type > 3);
        }



        cout << endl << endl << "Currency Type" << endl;
        cout << endl << "1.USD   2.GHC   3.EUR" << endl << endl;
        cin >> Currency;

         if (Currency == 1){
            Currency_type = "USD";
        }
         if (Currency == 2){
            Currency_type = "GHC";
        }
         if (Currency == 3){
            Currency_type = "EUR";
        }
        if (Currency < 1 || Currency > 3){
         do{
            cout << endl << endl << "Input Error please try again " << endl;
            cout << endl << "1.USD   2.GHC   3.EUR" << endl << endl;
            cin >> Currency;
        }
        while (Currency < 1 || Currency > 3);
        }

        cout << endl << endl << "Specify title" << endl;
        cout << endl << "1.Mrs   2.Mr   3.Miss   4.Ms" << endl << endl;
        cin >> Title;

         if (Title == 1){
            User_Title = "Mrs";
        }
         if (Title == 2){
            User_Title = "Mr";
        }
         if (Title == 3){
            User_Title = "Miss";
        }
         if (Title == 4){
            User_Title = "Ms";
        }
        if (Title < 1 || Title > 4){
         do{
            cout << endl << endl << "Input Error please try again " << endl;
            cout << endl << "1.Mrs   2.Mr   3.Miss   4.Ms" << endl << endl;
            cin >> Title;
        }
        while (Title < 1 || Title > 4);
        }

       
        cout << endl << endl << "By completing this form you agree to the terms and conditions that govern your account and your relationship with the bank" << endl << endl;
        cout << endl << "1.Register   2.Cancel" << endl << endl;
        cin >> Register;

         if (Register == 1){
            cout << endl << endl << "Registration success" << endl << endl;
        }
         if (Register == 2){
            cout << endl << endl << "See you soon" << endl;
        }
         if (Register < 1 || Register > 2){
         do{
            cout << endl << endl << "Input Error please try again " << endl;
            cout << endl << "1.Register   2.Cancel" << endl << endl;
            cin >> Register;
        }
        while (Register < 1 || Register > 2);
         }

        cout << endl << "Create a password for logins" << endl <<endl;
        cin >> Password;

        Account_Number = 85;
        cout << endl << endl << "Your Account Number is " << Account_Number << endl << endl;

        RecordFile << Account_Number << " " << Password << endl;

        User_Credentials << "Name : " << User_Title << " " << FirstName << " " << LastName << endl;
        User_Credentials << "Email : " << Email << endl;
        User_Credentials << "Digital Address : " << Digital_Address << endl;
        User_Credentials << "Date Of Birth : " << DOB << endl;
        User_Credentials << "Occupation : " << Occupation << endl;
        User_Credentials << "Nationality : " << Nationality << endl;
        User_Credentials << "Marital Status : " << Marital_Status << endl;
        User_Credentials << "Contact : " << Telephone  << endl;
        User_Credentials << "Account Type : " << User_Account_Type << endl;
        User_Credentials << "Currency : " << Currency_type << endl;

        User_Credentials.close();
        RecordFile.close();


    }
    else if (User_Activity == 2){

    ifstream InputFile;
    InputFile.open("record.txt", std::ios_base::in);

    cout << endl << endl << "Enter Account Number to Login" << endl << endl;
    cin >> ACN;

    cout << endl << endl << "Enter Password to login" << endl << endl;
    cin >> Pass_word;

    if (InputFile >> Account_Number && InputFile >> Password && Account_Number == ACN && Password == Pass_word) {
        cout << endl << "Welcome Back" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << endl << "Login Error, Please Create Account or check credentials" << endl;
    }

    InputFile.close();

    }
}
```

I Really don't know how this is gon work but that's what i want to do

Comment: With `User_Credentials.open("credentials.txt")` you recreate the file, truncating any existing contents of the file. That means everything already in the file will be lost. What does your beginner material (books, tutorials, class-notes) say about opening files?

Comment: And please try to create a [mre] to show us, with emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: Side issue: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: Also, get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this cast that means changing `ifstream InputFile; InputFile.open("record.txt");` to `ifstream InputFile("record.txt");`. Also, you don't need to call `InputFile.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: *"Everything works perfectly fine but the thing is that everytime a user creates an account, it replaces the old credentials stored in the already existing file."* -- Given the "perfectly fine" assertion, I have come to the conclusion that this is the desired behavior. Because if there was even a tiny problem with the functionality, it would not be "perfectly" fine. The lack of the tiniest flaw is the nature of "perfect". *Did you mean "almost fine"?*

Answer (score 0):

> ofstream RecordFile;
> RecordFile.open("record.txt");

In ofstream by default files are opened in ios::out mode which means, that if a file doesn't exist then it is created, but if exists then it is cleared.
use `ios::app` to append to record.txt.